# ¿Por qué la App final no encuentra los archivos en el directorio "res" de Android?

Tags: android, archivo

Hace tiempo que publico mi aplicación con algunos archivos ubicados en esta ruta: `res/raw`.

Antes de publicar una nueva versión de la App yo genero un archivo `.apk` y lo instalo en el dispositivo físico para verificar que no hay ningún error.

Pues bien, desde hoy, me están fallando todos los archivos que tengo en `res/raw`, no los encuentra. Lo curioso es que:

- en el emulador SÍ los encuentra
- si genero un archivo `.apk` NO los encuentra
- pero si paso los archivos al directorio `assets` SÍ los encuentra, tanto en el emulador como en el archivo `.apk`.

¿Ha cambiado algo en Android y no me he enterado? ¿Por qué en `assets` los encuentra siempre y en `res/raw` sólo los encuentra cuando pruebo la App en el emulador?

Este es el código que uso para leer los archivos:

```
public LiveData<String> getText(String rawPath) {
    try {
        InputStream in = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getClassLoader()).getResourceAsStream(rawPath);
        byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
        mText.setValue(new String(b));
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mText.setValue( String.format("Error: <br>%s",e.getMessage()));
    }
    return mText;
}
```

Lo que hay en `rawPath` es la ruta y el nombre del archivo que quiero leer.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a las carpetas de `res` dentro de la app o una externa? Si es el primer caso, la documentación dice que deberías abrirlos con [`Resources.openRawResource`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourceTypes)

Comment: @Mateo la carpeta se encuentra en la ruta: `app/src/main/res/raw`, voy a probar com el método que me sugieres, lo raro es que hasta ayer no daba problema.

Comment: O bien los pasaré todos al directorio `assets`, pues según dice en el enlace que me pasaste: *Sin embargo, si necesitas acceder a los nombres de los archivos originales y a la jerarquía de archivos, puedes considerar la posibilidad de guardar algunos recursos en el directorio `assets/` (en lugar de `res/raw/`). A los archivos de `assets/`no se les asigna un ID de recurso, por lo cual puedes leerlos solamente mediante AssetManager.*

Comment: ¿Qué error está mostrando, un FileNotFoundException (ENOENT) ?

Comment: @Jorgesys sí, mostraba un `FileNotFound`, pero ese problema empezó apenas hoy, la App llevaba años funcionando. Al final he pasado los archivos a `assets`, había querido evitar eso para no tener que estar pasando el contexto, pero como estoy trabajando con Dagger/Hilt y MVVM pues no hay problema, puedo inyectar el contexto en mi repositorio.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema puede generarse al obtener el `InputStream`, en esta línea:

```
InputStream in = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getClassLoader()).getResourceAsStream("/raw/archivo.txt");
```

Esto puede funcionar para archivos dentro de `/assets,` pero para archivos dentro de `/raw` no es lo ideal.

Lo ideal para asegurar obtener los recursos dentro del directorio `/raw` es indicando el ID del recurso haciendo referencia a este directorio (R.raw.archivo), usando [openRawResource(int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int)) de esta forma:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.archivo);
```